# send instant message to 3rd party messaging service like Yahoo, Skype, MSN

Tags: php, instant-messaging

Is there a way to send an instant message from your PHP code to a formal messaging service like Yahoo Messenger, Skype or MSN messenger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`libpurple`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpurple/). It has PHP bindings.

> This libpurple PHP binding, which defines a set of internal classes, gives a possibility to use aol and icq (oscar), yahoo, msn, jabber, irc and much more protocols directly from PHP. Write your own IM chat client in PHP, as simply as PHP enables it.

For Skype you will need [their COM Control](http://blogs.skype.com/devzone/2006/02/skype_com_api_and_skype_contac.html). Then you can use the [COM extension in PHP](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) to interface with Skype.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to http://code.google.com/p/phpmsnclass/ . I think that is what you want.

MSN class for php, support MSNP9 (MSN 6.2) and MSNP15 (WLM 8.1), use as a bot or just send message to MSN or Yahoo (via MSN, you need Yahoo 8.1 to communicate with MSN). Support OIM (offline message) if using MSNP15.